# Definitions sass in quasar

Tags: quasar-framework

i get this problem when i try to start my app..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Y6p.jpg)

i tried to update my quasar but it still dont work..:-([enter image description here]
with this command "yarn add -D rollup-plugin-sass-migrator sass-migrator"

and with this to " yarn global add @quasar/cli"
whitout success.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZ7Q.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)